# js как передать hash с одной страницы на другую

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как передать содержимое hash ссылки с одной страницы на другую страницу этого же сайта

То есть, у меня формируется hash страницы по выборке селектов
на пример site.ru/?filters=do-morya%5B22%5D%7Ckomnat%5B25%5D

как сделать передачу хэша: ?filters=do-morya%5B22%5D%7Ckomnat%5B25%5D нажатием на кнопку
на другую страницу site.ru/shop/+мой_хэш

По средствам формы или только js

Как это реализовать ?

Comment: Хэш хранится в переменной? Если да, при нажатии кнопки сделать что-то вроде `window.location.href = 'site.ru/shop/?' + hash;`

Comment: @Quazimorda а если не хранится в переменной, то выпарсить его регулярным выражением в переменную. А автору нужно поучится задавать вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Толком не понял, как он формируется, но для того, чтобы передать его па другую страницу, на ней должен бать такой принимающий код:

```js
var searched = location.search;
alert(searched);
```

Взято от сюда: [Передача и обработка данных в html-файле](https://www.spravkaweb.ru/javascript/sovet/get/)